# How to find PlaceHolder controls from User Control

Tags: c#

I have two usercontrol name called UC_1 & UC_2.

In UC_1 I have one placeholder. I would like to refer that placeholder from UC_2.

I tried below codes but i am getting null error:

```
string userControlName = "UC_1.ascx";
System.Web.UI.UserControl userControl = null;

PlaceHolder objPlaceHolder = ((TimeReportUC)Page.FindControl("placeHolderID")).FindControl("placeHolderID") as PlaceHolder;
                userControl = (System.Web.UI.UserControl)Page.LoadControl(userControlName);
                objPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

Comment: A UserControl accessing other UserControl is not a good design practice. Why do you need that feature?

Comment: It's easily done but you may be confusing data with gui, not a good thing.  When one usercontrol addresses another's elements, this is known as close coupling.  If you don't mind that you can simply create a static instance of what you want.  I often inject UserControls into ContentControls that are placeholders, simply by creating an interface that accepts a user control.  Simply inject what you want.  Otherwise you can fire events to just send data.

Comment: can any one please share how i can do it ?